# Cordova - build iOS with importing images

Tags: ios, cordova

I can use the Cordova build command **cordova platform add ios** and **cordova build ios** to add and build my iOS project.

After building, I can open the Xcode and run it on my simulator or device but there are some images I have to import into the **"Resources"** directory in Xcode after every **"add and build"** and this is a manual process I have to do every time after I add iOS and build it. These images are not the "splash" images or any "icons". These are the other assets within the application.

I was wondering if there are any commands that I can use while adding and building cordova projects for iOS so that I don't need to **"manually import"** all my assets in my Xcode environment?

OR, can I include all my assets (images) in the cofig.xml file so that after add and build, they are all available in "Resources" directory in Xcode automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your images means icon images.I had the same issue with cordova build. So I used phonegap build and it makes a resource folder inside WWW folder. You don't have to use phonegap but create a resource folder inside WWW folder. Then  put all your android/ios images inside resource folder. Yes reference your icon images in the root's config.xml file. This will copy all the images to your ios/android platform's in every build and you don't have to manually copy them.

Answer (score 0):

See following link:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface

The section where say

"Running commands to add or remove platforms affects the contents of the project's platforms directory, where each specified platform appears as a subdirectory. The www source directory is reproduced within each platform's subdirectory, appearing for example in platforms/ios/www or platforms/android/assets/www. Because the CLI constantly copies over files from the source www folder, you should only edit these files and not the ones located under the platforms subdirectories. If you use version control software, you should add this source www folder, along with the merges folder, to your version control system. (More information about the merges folder can be found in the Customize Each Platform section below.)

WARNING: When using the CLI to build your application, you should not edit any files in the /platforms/ directory unless you know what you are doing, or if documentation specifies otherwise. The files in this directory are routinely overwritten when preparing applications for building, or when plugins are reinstalled."

Copy the resource to the (projectName)/www directory, they will be copied over to your platform directory when you compile for that platform.